# Applescript: Getting week number from file name

Tags: applescript

I have lots of pics from my smartphone. The file name format for all of them is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.jpg

I need to sort them into the folders according to the week number.

I have no problems moving files to folders with AppleScript :) I also have no problems defining a week number for a given date. I have a problem (as I think) with syntax or even data types but I cannot understand where the problem lies.

Here's what I'm using.

1. I have a function for defining a week number for a given date
2. I scan through my folder and get all the names into the list
3. I parse the names to get yyyy, mm and dd as variables
4. Then I try to call for my function with these variables - and here's where the problem starts.

Please take a look at this example of my code:

```
property DBFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:lyubovberezina:Dropbox:DB"
property CUFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:lyubovberezina:Dropbox:Camera Uploads"

on weekNumber(_inputDate)

script Week_Number_Extras

    on dateOfFirstWeekOfYear(_year)
        -- Get Monday of first week number
        set _date to current date
        set year of _date to _year
        set month of _date to 1
        set day of _date to 1
        set time of _date to 0

        -- Get the first Thursday of this year
        repeat until weekday of _date is Thursday
            set _date to _date + (24 * 60 * 60)
        end repeat

        -- Return the Monday before
        set _date to _date - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60)

        return _date
    end dateOfFirstWeekOfYear

end script

-- Make a copy of the passed date object to avoid changes to the original
copy _inputDate to _targetDate

-- Reset the time and go back to Monday
set time of _targetDate to 0
repeat until weekday of _targetDate is Monday
    set _targetDate to _targetDate - (24 * 60 * 60)
end repeat

-- Get the date of the first week for the current year and the next one
tell Week_Number_Extras
    set _matchDate to dateOfFirstWeekOfYear(year of _targetDate)
    set _nextYearsFirstWeekDate to dateOfFirstWeekOfYear((year of _targetDate) + 1)
end tell

-- Exit early, if the current week is the first one of next year
if _targetDate = _nextYearsFirstWeekDate then return 1

-- Count up until the target date is reached
set _weekNumber to 1
repeat until _targetDate = _matchDate
    set _matchDate to _matchDate + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    set _weekNumber to _weekNumber + 1
end repeat

return _weekNumber
end weekNumber

tell application "Finder"
set this_folder to folder CUFolder
set this_list to every file of this_folder
repeat with i in this_list
    set fileName to name of i
    set fileYear to characters 1 thru 4 of fileName as string
    set fileMonth to characters 6 thru 7 of fileName as string
    set fileDay to characters 9 thru 10 of fileName as string
end repeat
end tell

set theNewDate to date (fileMonth & "/" & fileDay & "/" & fileYear)
weekNumber(theNewDate)
```

In this case the line

```
set theNewDate1 to date (fileMonth & "/" & fileDay & "/" & fileYear)
```

is working ok (I mean, no errors) but as it's outside the loop it gives the result for the last image in the loop only.
But if I move it to the loop then it gives an error:

```
property DBFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:lyubovberezina:Dropbox:DB"
property CUFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:lyubovberezina:Dropbox:Camera Uploads"

on weekNumber(_inputDate)

script Week_Number_Extras

    on dateOfFirstWeekOfYear(_year)
        -- Get Monday of first week number
        set _date to current date
        set year of _date to _year
        set month of _date to 1
        set day of _date to 1
        set time of _date to 0

        -- Get the first Thursday of this year
        repeat until weekday of _date is Thursday
            set _date to _date + (24 * 60 * 60)
        end repeat

        -- Return the Monday before
        set _date to _date - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60)

        return _date
    end dateOfFirstWeekOfYear

end script

-- Make a copy of the passed date object to avoid changes to the original
copy _inputDate to _targetDate

-- Reset the time and go back to Monday
set time of _targetDate to 0
repeat until weekday of _targetDate is Monday
    set _targetDate to _targetDate - (24 * 60 * 60)
end repeat

-- Get the date of the first week for the current year and the next one
tell Week_Number_Extras
    set _matchDate to dateOfFirstWeekOfYear(year of _targetDate)
    set _nextYearsFirstWeekDate to dateOfFirstWeekOfYear((year of _targetDate) + 1)
end tell

-- Exit early, if the current week is the first one of next year
if _targetDate = _nextYearsFirstWeekDate then return 1

-- Count up until the target date is reached
set _weekNumber to 1
repeat until _targetDate = _matchDate
    set _matchDate to _matchDate + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    set _weekNumber to _weekNumber + 1
end repeat

return _weekNumber
end weekNumber

tell application "Finder"
set this_folder to folder CUFolder
set this_list to every file of this_folder
repeat with i in this_list
    set fileName to name of i
    set fileYear to characters 1 thru 4 of fileName as string
    set fileMonth to characters 6 thru 7 of fileName as string
    set fileDay to characters 9 thru 10 of fileName as string
    set theNewDate to date (fileMonth & "/" & fileDay & "/" & fileYear)
    weekNumber(theNewDate)
end repeat
end tell
```

The error is given fight after the first file is taken:

```
get name of document file "2013-01-02 02.43.21.jpg" of folder "Camera Uploads" of folder "Dropbox" of folder "lyubovberezina" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    --> "2013-01-02 02.43.21.jpg"
get date "01/02/2013"
    --> error number -1728 from date "01/02/2013"
Result:
error "Finder got an error: Can’t get date \"01/02/2013\"." number -1728 from date "Wednesday, January 2, 2013 12:00:00 AM"
```

I am an almost total newbie in Applescript so I cannot understand why the code is working outside the loop and not working inside the loop. I would appreciate any help with this matter.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use a shell script at least for the week number part:

`do shell script "date -jf %F 2013-07-19 +%V"`

`cd ~/Dropbox/Camera\ Uploads; for f in *; do d=../DB/$(date -jf %F ${f:0:10} +%Y-%V "$f"); mkdir -p $d; mv "$f" $d; done`

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to your original format of:

```
set theNewDate to current date
set theNewDate's year to fileYear
set theNewDate's month to fileMonth
set theNewDate's day to fileDay
```

Also:

set _date to _date + (24 * 60 * 60)
is the same as
set _date to _date + days

set _date to _date - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60)
is the same as 
set _date to _date - (3 * days)

set _matchDate to _matchDate + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
is the same as
set _matchDate to _matchDate + weeks